# How do you deploy a Vue Native app on iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, vue.js, native

Can anyone point me to how to deploy a Vue Native app on the iOS app store? I have seen a couple of articles explaining how to do this for the Play store, but nothing for iOS.

React Native usually has an iOS build folder which you can open from XCode and deploy your app. But I don't see anything like that for Vue Native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because vue-native runs on Expo, releasing your app to iOS app store can be accomplished through the [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/uploading-apps/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30635925)